# Saving a deleted row in a datatable to be deleted later in a database

Tags: c#, datatable

Sorry if the title is a bit vague, but I'm trying to think of a good way to do this right now. We are using .NET 3.5, by the way.

Example code:

```
if (ExistsInDB(dt.Rows.Find(rowID)))
     dt.Rows.Find(rowID).Delete();
else
     dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows.Find(rowID));
```

If the row exists in the database, mark it for deletion. Otherwise, remove it from the datatable.

Now, if I go ahead and change the DataRow's RowState property to Deleted via the DataRow.Delete() method, that works fine except I can't access information I would need to delete the row from the database when the user hits "Save Changes".

I don't want to store the rows in another datatable because I already have a lot of other data tables and I don't want to add more complexity to the object. I would put another column on the datatable with the name "ToBeDeleted" or something, but the tables get displayed in the program via a grid.

Essentially, I want to be able to flag a DataRow in a DataTable for deletion in the database later without resorting to throwing the DataRow into a List or adding another column to it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the deleted row's data by writing

```
row["ColumnName", DataRowVersion.Original]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use DataAdapter for this? You can learn how to do this at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzb1zw3x%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Thanks,
Vamyip